# How to find which row has the biggest sum in 2D array?

Tags: c

I have 2D array, I need to write a function to find which row has the biggest sum, and if there is more than one row with the same sum, I need to print no particular max. This is what I wrote so far:

```
int find_max_sum(int b[N][N])
{
    int row_sum = 0;
    int row_max = -1;
    int i,j,k;
    int counter=0;
    for(int i =0;i<N;i++)
    {
        row_sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            row_sum +=  b[i][j] ;
        }
        if(row_max < row_sum)
        {
            row_max = row_sum;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
       for (j= 0;j< N;j++)
       {
           if(k=row_max);
           counter++;
       }
    }
    if (counter>1)
        return(printf("No unique max.\n"));
    else
        return row_max;
}
```

Now I need help with the counter thing, and if the function is `int` how can it return prints? Is it possible?

Comment: Since `printf()` returns the number of characters printed, you can return its return value, but it probably isn't what you want.

Comment: Are you working on the same problem as [kayan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6457718/kayan) who asked [How to count how many maximum are in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780992/).  There are differences, but some of the code is remarkably similar.  As I noted in a comment there, you should be able to do the count of the number of times the maximum occurs in a single pass through the array. If the current value is higher than the current maximum, record the new maximum and set the count to 1, or if the current value is equal to the current maximum, add one to the count.

Comment: You have a bug with the assignment `if (k=row_max)` in the second set of nested loops.  You probably want `if (k == row_max)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define N 2
#define NO_UNIQUE -1

int find_max_sum(int b[][N])
{
    int row_sum, i, j;
    int row_max = -1;
    bool unique = false;

    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        row_sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            row_sum += b[i][j];

        if (row_max < row_sum) {
            row_max = row_sum;
            unique = true;
        } else if (row_max == row_sum)
            unique = false;
    }

    if (unique)
        return row_max;
    else {
        printf("No unique max.\n");
        return NO_UNIQUE;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int b[N][N] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    printf("Max sum is %d\n", find_max_sum(b));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He wants to pass an array. Why on earth would he use `int**`? That's just plain bad and incorrect advise. Please remove that part from your answer.

Comment: @Lundin Use`find_max_sum(int **b, int size)` may avoid `#define N` in the global environment, I think that's only flavor issue, so I just *suggest*. It's another choice to implement, why *bad and incorrect*?

Comment: Because pointers-to-pointers have nothing to do with arrays what-so-ever. A 2D array is not compatible with a pointer-to-pointer.  So it is bad and incorrect - it simply cannot be used - you'd have to change the caller code and for no good reason.The correct function definition in a real program without globals would be `find_max_sum (size_t size, int b[size][size])`.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, you're right! Thanks! And `size_t size` should be before `int b[size][size]`. I thought this discussion may help others, do you prefer that I modify my answer or let it be?

Comment: I would prefer you remove the advise to use `int**`. It is a good answer apart from that detail.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a third variable (let's call it `rowsWithMaxCount`) to store the amount of rows with the current max value such that:

- if you find a row with a new maximum then `rowsWithMaxCount = 1`
- if you find a row such that `row_max == row_sum` then `++rowsWithMaxCount`
- otherwise `rowsWithMaxCount` is unaffected

This will save you from looping the bidimensional array, which is a waste of code since you can obtain all the information you need with a single traversal of the array.

*"returning a printf"* doesn't make any sense and it's not possible, if you declare the function to return an `int` then you must return an `int`. Consider using a special value to signal the caller that there is no unique maximum value. Eg, assuming values are always positive:

```
static const int NO_UNIQUE_MAX = -1;

int find_max_sum(int b[N][N]) {
  ...
  if (counter > 1)
    return NO_UNIQUE_MAX;
  ...
}
```

But this will prevent you from returning the not-unique maximum value. If you need to return both then you could declare a new type, for example

```
struct MaxRowStatus {
  int value;
  int count;
};
```

So that you can precisely return both values from the function.

Comment: ok , so what you mean is i delete the loop to find counter ? and just add rowsWithMaxCount ?

Comment: hi jack, it os not important in this assigment to make the code small.. i just want it to work! and now the count thing is not working ..

Answer (score 0):

You may be over-thinking the function, if I understand what you want correctly. If you simply want to return the row index for the row containing a *unique* max sum, or print `no unique max.` if the max sum is non-unique, then you only need a single iteration through the array using a single set of nested loops.

You can even pass a pointer as a parameter to the function to make the *max sum* available back in your calling function (`main()` here) along with the index of the row in which it occurs. The easiest way to track the uniqueness is to keep a toggle (`0, 1`) tracking the state of the sum.

An example would be:

```
int maxrow (int (*a)[NCOL], size_t n, long *msum)
{
    long max = 0;
    size_t i, j, idx = 0, u = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {       /* for each row     */
        long sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < NCOL; j++)  /* compute row sum  */
            sum += a[i][j];
        if (sum == max) u = 0;      /* if dup, unique 0 */
        if (sum > max)   /* if new max, save idx, u = 1 */
            max = sum, idx = i, u = 1;
    }
    if (u) {    /* if unique, update msum, return index */
        if (msum) *msum = max;
        return idx;
    }
    fprintf (stderr, "no unique max.\n");
    return -1;  /* return -1 if non-unique */
}
```

(**note:** if you don't care about having the max sum available back in the caller, simply pass `NULL` for the `msum` parameter)

A short test program could be the following. Simply uncomment the second row to test the behavior of the function for a *non-unique* max sum:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { NCOL = 7 };

int maxrow (int (*a)[NCOL], size_t n, long *msum)
{
    long max = 0;
    size_t i, j, idx = 0, u = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {       /* for each row     */
        long sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < NCOL; j++)  /* compute row sum  */
            sum += a[i][j];
        if (sum == max) u = 0;      /* if dup, unique 0 */
        if (sum > max)   /* if new max, save idx, u = 1 */
            max = sum, idx = i, u = 1;
    }
    if (u) {    /* if unique, update msum, return index */
        if (msum) *msum = max;
        return idx;
    }
    fprintf (stderr, "no unique max.\n");
    return -1;  /* return -1 if non-unique */
}

int main (void) {

    int a[][7] = {{ 0, 9, 3, 6, 4, 8, 3 },
            /* { 3, 9, 2, 7, 9, 1, 6 }, uncomment for test */
                { 6, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4 },
                { 4, 3, 3, 8, 1, 2, 5 },
                { 3, 9, 2, 7, 9, 1, 6 }},
        maxidx;
    long sum = 0;
    size_t nrow = sizeof a/sizeof *a;

    if ((maxidx = maxrow (a, nrow, &sum)) != -1)
        printf (" max sum '%ld' occurs at row : %d  (0 - indexed).\n",
                sum, maxidx);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

For the unique sum case:

```
$ ./array2Drow
 max sum '37' occurs at row : 3  (0 - indexed).
```

non-unique case:

```
$ ./array2Drow
no unique max.
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions, or if I misinterpreted your needs.