# How to count how many maximum are in an array?

Tags: c

I have this function, and I want your help to find if there is more than one maximum. If more than one maximum exists, I want to print "no unique max".

The code below successfully finds the maximum, but the counter, which countes how many times a maximum appears is not working and I get this message:

> suggest braces around empty body in c

```
int find_max(int b[N][N])
{
   int max = b[0][0];
   int x,y;
   int counter=0;
   int a=0,v=0,c=0;
   for (x = 0; x < N; x++)
   {
       for (y = 0; y < N; y++)
       {
           if (max < b[x][y])
           {
               max = b[x][y];
                a=x;
                v=y;
           }
       }
   }

    c=((a*10)+v);
    for (x = 0; x < N; x++)
   {
       for (y = 0; y < N; y++)
       {
           if(max);
           {
           counter++;
           }
       }
   }
 if(counter>1)
   printf("no uniqe max");
else
   return c;
}
```

Comment: You should be able to do the whole lot in a single pass through the array.  If the current value is higher than the current maximum, record the new maximum and set the count to 1.  If the current value is equal to the current maximum, add one to the count.  Otherwise, ignore the row.

Comment: `if(max);` does nothing because of the `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first glance :

```
if(max == b[x][y]) // not if(max);
{
  counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem (at least one problem) is the following line:

```
if(max);
```

If max is not zero, then this will always be true.  I think you want something like:

```
if(b[x][y] == max)
```

(note: both the comparison and the removal of the ';')

The warning is (I suspect) coming from the ';' after your 'if', this terminates the if and the next section '{...}' is always executed, it is not associated with the if.

Comment: i am still getting the same comment

Comment: Sorry, I put an extra ')' in the if.  I've corrected it.  What OS and compiler are you using?  Usually, when a compiler issues a warning or error it provides and associated line number.  You may want to post that information.

Comment: The warning might be because of no return value when there is no unique max... Try returning -1 when there is no unique max